# Web audio API - play two audio files syncronized with precise timing audio without buffering

Tags: reactjs, web-audio-api

I'm using react and i'm trying to play two audio files with perfect sync (let's say drums and guitar), iv'e tried to use `<audio/>` elements, loop on them and run `play()` function, but sometimes it's going out of sync.
after a research i find that `audioBuffer` can do it precisely with the `start()` function, the problem is that i need to fetch the whole audio file before i can play it, and i want the ability to use videos, and if i fetch the video before i play it, it could take a long time because of the file size.

can i use something else than `audioBuffer` to achive precise sync between two audio files?

in the MDN Docs of the `audioBuffer` they say:

> This interface is especially useful for playing back audio which has particularly stringent timing accuracy requirements, such as for sounds that must match a specific rhythm and can be kept in memory rather than being played from disk or the network. **To play sounds which require accurate timing but must be streamed from the network or played from disk, use a `AudioWorkletNode` to implement its playback.**

but i don't find a way to use `AudioWorkletNode` to achive my goal.